# Regex for X or not Y

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string of text that's broken up by semi-colons, so I have a regex that captures `[^\;]+`.  However, it's bugging because the content contains HTML apostrophes ( `&#39;` ).

How can I write a regex that will capture everything but the semi-colons unless the semi-colon is part of the HTML apostrophe?

Comment: Why aren't you parsing the HTML?

Comment: I swear, if I had a nickel for every time... http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/576139

Comment: You can't. This isn't what regular expressions are for.

Comment: Can we just have a bot that posts that link whenever someone has the terms HTML and regex in a single question? I don't get why people feel the need to make things harder for themselves. There are so many tools to do this exact job, and instead they want to reinvent the wheel with something really not designed for the job.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: You should entity-decode the HTML before splitting.

Comment: @Chris I've already read that question.  It is irrelevant to what I am trying to do.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: What version of BeautifulSoup? BS4 should convert the entities into unicode characters automatically: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup

Comment: No chance of just getting the answer to my question, which is how to make a regex that does what I"m asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(&\S+?;|[^;])+
```

Match HTML entities as if they were single characters.